# Unable to see the files hidden by a batch script

Tags: windows-7, command-line

If I hide a file using command `attrib +s +h file.txt`. Then set the option `'view hidden files'` in Windows 7, but it is not possible to see `file.txt`. Why can't I see the files hidden by the batch script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the `+s` parameter you would also need to uncheck the `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` checkbox in "Folder Options" - "View" to see the file you've hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
dir /S /aH
```

also

```
dir /B /S /a-D
```